# Broken longrightarrow

Tags: math-mode, arrows

I have found a strange behavior. By compiling the following formula in a LaTex file,

```
\[ {\small \longrightarrow } \]
```

I obtain the broken arrow

[image]

Is it a bug of my distribution ?

Comment: As always on the site please provide a full minimal example. Here it is relevant to know what font size and fonts you are using, none of which you are showing us.

Comment: it is a bug in your document, You would have had a warning that size commands should not be used in math mode. Dont ignore warnings!

Comment: look in your log: Command \small invalid in math mode. just use \[ {\longrightarrow } \]

Comment: @daleif I understand your point. I did not know that the font size could be relevant.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay. How do I proceed to have a smaller formula (which contains other things than the arrow of course) ? Another solution would be use the multline environment of course.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher impossible to say just from the example   `\scriptstyle` if it is in math or `\small\[....` or ....

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher In general on this site alwas provide code that others can test as is, then it is a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to decrease the size of the symbol produced by `\longrightarrow`, you should either preface the command by `\small`, `\footnotesize`, etc *before* entering math mode or employ `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle` directives *inside* math mode.

[image]

Actually, judging by this screenshot, it may be a good idea not to use `\tiny` or `\scriptscriptstyle` together with `\longrightarrow`...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
$\longrightarrow$ 
{\small $\longrightarrow$} 
{\footnotesize $\longrightarrow$}
{\scriptsize $\longrightarrow$}
$\scriptstyle\longrightarrow$
{\tiny $\longrightarrow$}
$\scriptscriptstyle\longrightarrow$
\end{document}
```